# Where can I get these header files?

Tags: c, compilation, header-files, alsa

I'm attempting to compile SndObj, and I need some header files. Which Debian packages do I need to obtain all the missing header files?

```
Checking for C header file alsa/asoundlib.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file soundcard.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file jack/jack.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file m_pd.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file ladspa.h... (cached) no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Debian package contents search page](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents)

(give a man a fish, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I used

> apt-file search asoundlib

Seems at least that file is in `libasound-dev` .